# Python 2.7.10 and scrapy Installation on CentOS 6.7 AWS

Tags: python, linux, amazon-web-services, centos6

I know there are similar posts, but I've followed many instructions on installing python. (I'm no linux expert)

But I've constantly hit different problems...

The latest problem was this error:

```
Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement Twisted>=10.0.0 (from scrapy) (from versions: )

Some externally hosted files were ignored as access to them may be unreliable (use --allow-external Twisted to allow). No matching distribution found for Twisted>=10.0.0 (from scrapy)
```

This is my third try after wiping the server clean and starting from scratch.

Can someone help me with setting up python 2.7.10 and scrapy in a CentOS 6.7 AWS server? What do other dev tools do I need to install beforehand?

**EDIT**

I'm accessing the CentOS AWS server through putty and I've read that I shouldn't overwrite python 2.6.6 on it. I've installed python 2.7.10 on it successfully.

I know this because the `python` command opens the 2.6.6 IDLE while `python2.7` opens 2.7.10.

**EDIT**

I have two instances of Python now the system python 2.6.6 and python 2.7.10.

I also installed a virtualenv of 2.7.10 and installed scrapy.

Now my problem is this whenever I try to open the scrapy shell:

```
libpython2.7.so.1.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

Comment: Start with official Python package installation guide https://packaging.python.org/en/latest/installing.html